# VMware-Ubuntu 16.04 automatically log out

Tags: 16.04, vmware

I use the VMware to run Ubuntu
Every "one hour" my ubuntu will automically log out 
I have already changed the setting and also change "timeout",but is not effective
the following text is my log file
Did anyone meet this problem before?
Please help me
thank you

```
Feb 28 15:17:01 yangningfan-virtual-machine CRON[82277]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 28 15:17:01 yangningfan-virtual-machine killer[82280]: kill(15, 79341) user=yangnin+ command=notify-osd nice=0
Feb 28 15:17:01 yangningfan-virtual-machine systemd[79135]: Reached target Shutdown.
Feb 28 15:17:01 yangningfan-virtual-machine systemd[79135]: Stopped target Default.
Feb 28 15:17:01 yangningfan-virtual-machine systemd[79135]: Stopped target Basic System.
Feb 28 15:17:01 yangningfan-virtual-machine systemd[79135]: Stopped target Paths.
Feb 28 15:17:01 yangningfan-virtual-machine systemd[79135]: Stopped target Timers.
Feb 28 15:17:01 yangningfan-virtual-machine systemd[79135]: Stopped target Sockets.
Feb 28 15:17:01 yangningfan-virtual-machine systemd[79135]: Starting Exit the Session...
```

Comment: I don't understand your configuration/question. Please explain why the VM has to start every hour. What 'setting' did you change? What 'timeout' do you mean?  What 'problem' are you referring to??